# Angular forms: Triggering revalidation of field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-forms

I have a form with two fields: validFrom and validUntil. ValidUntil has a custom validator that will render the field invalid if the value is before the value in validFrom. This works fine as long as it's validUntil that I'm editing. However, when the form is in invalid state, and I edit the validFrom value to something earlier, I'd expect the form to validate, but it doesn't. How do I trigger revalidation?

I tried `vm.form.validUntil.$validate()`, which seems to do something, but only after the second time I update the validFrom value.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `$timeout` did the trick. The problem was that in the validator, which was dependent on a scope variable, that scope variable wasn't updated yet with the value just entered. I'm not sure if this is the best solution, if someone else has a better one, I'd love to hear it.

```
vm.promotion[key] = value;

$timeout(function() { // this was added
    if (key === 'validFrom') {
        vm.form.validUntil.$validate();
    }

    if (vm.form.$valid) {
        PromotionManager.update(vm.promotion);
    }
});
```